# Large list of lists to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of list of lists; let's call it `mat`. I want to convert it to dataframe.

Here are some sample contents.

```
[14]][[1000]]
[[14]][[1000]][[1]]
[1] 51

[[14]][[1000]][[2]]
[1] 10

[[14]][[1000]][[3]]
[1] "C Hou" "C Han"

[[14]][[1000]][[4]]
[1] "Communication Middleware and Software for QoS Control in Distributed Real-Time EnvironmentsSpecifically, we consider the following innovative research components "

[[14]][[1000]][[5]]
[1] "COMPSAC International Computer Software and Applications Conference"
```

They are: paper ID, author ID, coauthor names, paper title, and journal title.

This large list is generated from 14 text files, and I happened to pick the last one printed to the console, thus the "first" index of [[14]]; the "second" index of [[1000]] is referring to 1000th entry or record in the text file, and [[1]] is the "index" of the "column names" (paper ID, author ID, coauthor names, paper title, and journal title).

Now, I have tried a few things on SO to no luck; I always get the error `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0` when I try to convert it to dataframe.

Moreover, when I use the code `x = mat[[1]]`, wanting to extract one list of list, the one from the first text files, I could not even "view" it. `View(x)` produces the same error: `Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`.

I am completely lost as to how to convert this large list into a dataframe that I can use. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate some sample data that matches the structure of your data (I hope I got it right):

```
## Create sample data:
createList <- function(j){
    nElem <- 5
    paperIDVec <- sample.int(1000, nElem, replace = FALSE) 
    authorIDVec <- sample.int(1000, nElem, replace = FALSE) 
    coauthorsList <- lapply(1:nElem, function(ii){
                paste("Coauthor", 1:sample.int(3, 1))           
            })
    paperTitleVec <- paste("Some brilliant idea that author", authorIDVec, "had")
    journalVec <- vapply(1:nElem, function(ii) paste("Journal", 
                        paste(LETTERS[sample.int(26, 3, replace = TRUE)], collapse = "")), character(1))
    outList <- lapply(1:nElem, function(ii){
                list(paperIDVec[ii], authorIDVec[ii],
                        coauthorsList[[ii]], paperTitleVec[ii],
                        journalVec[ii])         
            })
}
mat <- lapply(1:4, createList)
```

Using this data and following the approach of @chinsoon12 I first pasted the entries together to create a single character for each entry (e.g. a vector of three co-authors `c("Mr. X", "Mrs. J", "Mr. M")` becomes `"Mr. X, Mrs. J, Mr. M"`), and then turned the data into data frames and successively combined them to create one big data frame:

```
## Turn nested list into one data frame:
textFileDfList <- lapply(mat, function(listLevel2) {            
            ## Convert list on second level of hierarchy (= one text file)
            ## to a list of data frames (one for each entry)            
            dataFrameList <- lapply(listLevel2, function(listLevel3){
                        ## Paste multiple entries (e.g. vector of co-authors)
                        ## together to create a single character entry:
                        simplifiedList <- lapply(listLevel3, 
                                function(entries) paste(entries, collapse = ", "))
                        ## Create data.frame:
                        outDf <- as.data.frame(simplifiedList, 
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                                col.names =  c("paper ID", "author ID", "coauthor names", 
                                        "paper title", "journal title"))                                                    
                    })

            ## Combine data frames of the single entries to one data frame,
            ## containing all entries of the text file:
            textFileDf <- do.call('rbind', dataFrameList)           
        })
## Combine data frames of the text files to one big data frame:
bigDataFrame <- do.call('rbind', textFileDfList)

> head(bigDataFrame)
  paper.ID author.ID                     coauthor.names
1      862       990             Coauthor 1, Coauthor 2
2      688       400                         Coauthor 1
3      921       963 Coauthor 1, Coauthor 2, Coauthor 3
4      479       455             Coauthor 1, Coauthor 2
5      709       340                         Coauthor 1
6      936       591             Coauthor 1, Coauthor 2
                              paper.title journal.title
1 Some brilliant idea that author 990 had   Journal PZR
2 Some brilliant idea that author 400 had   Journal MQD
3 Some brilliant idea that author 963 had   Journal WFW
4 Some brilliant idea that author 455 had   Journal TZV
5 Some brilliant idea that author 340 had   Journal DCR
6 Some brilliant idea that author 591 had   Journal EGW
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. I will scrutinize this amazing code now. One last question, If I have called `mat = mat[[1]]`, to take only the first layer (the first text file), which layer should I modify so that it outputs a dataframe?

Comment: Only execute the code inside the first `lapply` with `listLevel2 <- mat[[1]]`. That should work.

Comment: I got it. I did it by removing `function(listLevel2) {            
            dataFrameList <- lapply(listLevel2, ` and then matched a few parenthesis. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

you can perform nested lapply to process each nested list as follows

```
papers <- do.call(rbind, lapply(mat, function(txtfile) {
    lapply(txtfile, function(entry) {
        #to handle multiple coauthors and paste into a single string
        l <- lapply(entry, function(eachcol) {
            paste(eachcol)
        })

        df <- as.data.frame(l)
        df
    })
}))
names(papers) <- c("paper ID", "author ID", "coauthor names", "paper title", "journal title")
```

I do not have the data to test it so do give me a shout if this still fails.

a related qn: why are you not reading the text files in as data.frames rather than lists?

Comment: For some reason rstudio is giving me mismatched parenthesis error, even when it looks like everything is matched.

Comment: updated. maybe u can `dput(mat)` so that we can test as well

Comment: I am not very familiar with dput even after some googling. After `dput(mat)`, the value returned is still a large list, and I am not sure what to do with that. Moreover, it still gives me the same error `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0`. Lastly, I didn't read this in as a text file is because this large list is the product of some complicated function... I will try to look into that function to see if it is possible to output a data frame instead of a list. Thanks!